# Why mpirun freeze in loop

Tags: python, linux, mpi

Here is my script and python code.

$ cat go

```
while true
do
echo "------->"
python3 -m mpi4py ./go.py
echo "<------"
done
```

This code run python go.py in loop.

$ cat go.py

```
import mpi4py.MPI as MPI

print( "######", MPI.Is_initialized())

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
comm_rank = comm.Get_rank()
comm_size = comm.Get_size()

# point to point communication
data_send = [comm_rank]*5
comm.send(data_send,dest=(comm_rank+1)%comm_size)
data_recv =comm.recv(source=(comm_rank-1)%comm_size)
print("my rank is %d, and Ireceived:" % comm_rank)
print( data_recv )

MPI.Finalize()

print( "######", MPI.Is_finalized())
```

This python code just print.

After I run this go script, the go.py execute and exit, when go.py execute again,
it got stuck.

$ mpirun --mca orte_base_help_aggregate 0 -np 2 sh ./go

```
------->
------->
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[27909,1],1]: A high-performance Open MPI point-to-point messaging module
was unable to find any relevant network interfaces:

Module: OpenFabrics (openib)
  Host: myvm20

Another transport will be used instead, although this may result in
lower performance.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[27909,1],0]: A high-performance Open MPI point-to-point messaging module
was unable to find any relevant network interfaces:

Module: OpenFabrics (openib)
  Host: myvm20

Another transport will be used instead, although this may result in
lower performance.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
###### True
###### True
my rank is 0, and Ireceived:
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
my rank is 1, and Ireceived:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
###### True
###### True
<------
------->
<------
------->
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[27909,1],0]: A high-performance Open MPI point-to-point messaging module
was unable to find any relevant network interfaces:

Module: OpenFabrics (openib)
  Host: myvm20

Another transport will be used instead, although this may result in
lower performance.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[27909,1],1]: A high-performance Open MPI point-to-point messaging module
was unable to find any relevant network interfaces:

Module: OpenFabrics (openib)
  Host: myvm20

Another transport will be used instead, although this may result in
lower performance.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and freeze for ever.

Why does it stuck, and how can I continue this script?

BTW:
I have two kind of job A/B to run, job A persist, job B finish and quit. So I can't run it as following:

```
while true
do
  echo "------->"
  mpirun -np 2 A : -np 2 B
  echo "<------"
done
```

Is there other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

long story short, you cannot do that.

here is what you should do instead

```
while true
do
  echo "------->"
  mpirun --mca orte_base_help_aggregate 0 -np 2 python3 -m mpi4py ./go.py
  echo "<------"
done
```

Comment: I have two kind of job A/B to run, job A persist, job B finish and quit. So I can't run it as following: mpirun -np 2 A :  -np 2 B, is there other way to do this?

Comment: if i understand correctly, you can `mpirun -np 2 A`, in which `A` enters a loop that `MPI_Comm_spawn()` job `B` on two tasks, wait for `B` to complete, `MPI_Comm_disconnect()` and then re-iterate. since this is a different question, you should make a new one and write a minimal example for `A` and `B` in order to clarify what you mean by *"persist"*